# does Ambari Agent generate host addresses

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, ambari

I am learning about cloudera and came across Ambari agent that resides in each host that is part of a hadoop cluster. So while configuring/creating the cluster does Ambari agent generate the IP addresses for the hosts and send them to DNS or is my understanding completely wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agent reports the host information to the Ambari server, it doesn't manipulate anything outside of the Hadoop processes.

The IP & hostname of the nodes would already be assigned prior to installation of the agent